# What's the capacity of ms access 2003?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

The limit of an access database. Because I only know of manipulating access 2003 database with vb.net. And were going to make an information system for a small hospital for our project. Is ms access still usable for a hospital with over 2000 patients per year?
Could you suggest some database if the ms access that I'm using no longer fits for our project.

Comment: Having a look at the other questions you have asked, I would honestly suggest that you respond to the commentors when they ask you for clarification, and accept those answers if they are ok for you!

Comment: Depending on your country, there may be stringent rules regarding the storage of medical data, HIPAA, for example, or these notes http://www.docusafe.com/legal_resources.html

Comment: Jet/ACE can be OK for HIPAA as long as the file is stored on a closed network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think it's a good idea to use Access for storing possibly **confidential** data about patients. If you have to regard security issues, better use a full-fledged client/server database. Since you are looking for something as an alternative to MS access, and if your server OS is MS Windows, [Microsoft SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) may be an option for you. If you want something that is smaller, mature and can run on other OSes, [Sybase SQL Anywhere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Anywhere) is a good option. I don't suggest Oracle, this is possibly oversized for someone who is looking for an Access replacement.

If you provide more information about number of (simultaneous) users and what kind of application(s) will use the database, me (and others) can give you a better suggestion what DB to use.

Answer (score 3):

@fupsduck and @Mark Wilkins both cite [Access Specifications and Limits](http://www.databasedev.co.uk/access_specifications.html), which applies to A2000, A2002 and A2003. All of the specifications apply to A97 and A2007 as well, except these (checked against the A97 and A2007 help files article on Access Specifications and added here for completeness):

#### Access 97

- max file size -- 1GB in Jet 3.x
- Modules -- 1024 (I don't know why later versions of Access limit it to decimal 1000 instead of a binary number)
- table handles -- 2048 in Jet 3.5 SP1 and up, 1024 in original Jet 3.5
- table size -- 1GB
- record size -- 2K in Jet 3.x (no Unicode). This limit is the data page size, since a record can't span two data pages (the Jet 4 data page is 4K).
- Number of ANDs in a WHERE or HAVING clause -- 40
- nested forms or reports -- 3

A few of the items (like characters in a recordsource/rowsource) are not specified in the A97 help file, but I seem to recall that rowsources are more limited in length in A97 than later.

#### Access 2007

- characters in a password -- 20

The following items are impacted by whether or not your query includes tables with multi-value fields. This is because a MV field is internally implemented as a proper many-to-many join, so any single MV field will use up 2 joins and 2 tables. It's not clear to me if having a table with a MV field in it uses up the resources, or if it uses them up only if you include the MV field in the SELECT statement. Multi-value fields are available only in ACCDB format, so for MDB format in A2007, this caveat does not apply.

- tables in a query -- 32*
- joins in a query -- 16*  <= not listed in A2003 help file
- AND operators in a WHERE or HAVING clause -- 99*
- characters in an SQL statement -- 64,000*

Comment: Jet 4.0 Databases (Access 2000 and greater), can have 2Gb File Size.

Comment: @Andreas Hoffmann: Yes, that's what the original cited article says, and that's why there was no need for me to repeat it.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.databasedev.co.uk/access_specifications.html) is one of the first google hits for limitations in Access. It's not completely clear to me which version that is for.  Nonetheless, you can probably find the limits easily for the version of interest with a bit of searching.

In reality, from a storage perspective, Access could likely store the records for 2000 patients a year ... but it doesn't seem like a good idea.  It does not handle multi-user environments very well at all, which I assume would be likely in this case.

As far as suggestions, you can get any number of people listing the one they like best. I would recommend [Advantage Database Server](http://www.sybase.com/products/databasemanagement/advantagedatabaseserver). But my suggestion could be considered a bit biased since I am one of the developers on it. There are quite a few database engines that will work. You will need to study them and probably make your own choice based on requirements and functionality provided by the database engine.

**Edit**  I probably should have been a bit more clear that I was not singling out Access specifically as having problems.  The issue is more with client/server versus non-client/server environments. It is a simple issue. With file-sharing database systems (of which MS Access is a member), the client makes the updates to the files. On a networked system, this introduces potential problems.  Even Microsoft [recognizes this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303528).  In the section of that article titled **Additional best practices for network environments**, it specifically says that the database can be corrupted if a client is stopped unexpectedly or if a network connection is dropped.

For example, I just now opened northwind.mdb and deleted the first Orders record. This resulted in 19 file writes to the database file. I tested the same thing over the network and counted 19 individual writes across the network. If the connection is dropped in the middle of that, then there is potential for corruption. With a client/server solution such as SQL Server, a record delete would be one single command sent to the server. It either gets there or it doesn't. If it reaches the server, it can be handled "atomically" by the server. With database environments, the ability to make logically consistent updates is critical. A record update often involves multiple file updates. Not only must the record itself be udpated, but there are often index updates (possibly multiple indexes and multiple page writes for each one in a b-tree), transactions, referential integrity, meta-data (e.g., record counts), etc.

Comment: Er, the first cited article states "The following details the specifications stated in the Microsoft Access Help files for Microsoft Access 2000, XP and 2003 versions". See my answer below which adds notations on the differences with A97.

Comment: 2000 records a year is trivial for Jet/ACE. Also, multi-user is trivial to implement properly for user populations as large as 15-25. Above that, it requires more skill, but basically the same designs that work well in client/server environments work well in Access/Jet/ACE (i.e., retrieve as little data as necessary to do the job at hand). Nonetheless, I am inclined to go with Doc Brown, and advise that security considerations with patient data argue for a more secure data store like SQL Server. -1 for being misinformed about Access/Jet/ACE and then spreading that misinformation.

Comment: Sorry about that. I did a poor job in my answer. I was referring to differences between client/server and non-client/server situations. A database update typically involves multiple updates to the file(s) involved (record update, meta-data updates, index updates, RI updates, transactions, etc.).  In a client/server situation a client crash (or network failure), it is more likely that any update will be treated "atomically" and will not be affected by a client-side problem and result in logical or physical corruption.

Comment: What's your point in outlining how Jet/ACE works? Perhaps there are people who've not thought through the whole thing and don't understand this, but it doesn't make Jet/ACE unsuitable for multi-user use at all.

Comment: I guess I don't really understand your question. Maybe my thought processes are atypical. I tend toward giving all the applicable information rather than hiding some. In this case, the information seems applicable. The original question was about using a particular product in a certain situation. Thus, a discussion of how the product works seems to make sense. If one update by a user causes 19 file writes, then 10 updates by 10 users may result in nearly 2000 individual file server updates across the network. Any failure potentially results in a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You would think you could find this on Microsoft's WEB site but only MS-Access 2007 comes up. At this site, it says the limits can be found in the help files:

http://www.databasedev.co.uk/access_specifications.html

Have you looked in the MS-Access 2003 help files?  Try searching for "limits".

Comment: The best search is "specification" -- the correct answer comes up even in the hideous A2000 help files.

Answer (score 0):

MS Access uses the Jet DB engine, which has a lot of limitations and is officially depreciated by Microsoft. If this a single client machine, SQLite would be a better choice. Otherwise something like MySQL/Postgres or any other multi-user DB.

Comment: Jet is not deprecated by Microsoft except for its current set of development tools. Many people cite the articles that say Jet is deprecated, but those articles apply only to VS and .NET. Jet is in full development for use with Access (it's now called ACE) and gaining an enormous number of enhancements for the next release of Access. Jet 4 is also shipped with every copy of Windows, since it's been part of the OS (used for managing the Active Directory data store) since Windows 2000.